# Android app crashes on virtual device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-emulator

I changed the android label in my manifest.xml

and this is the code in myactivity

```
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Why does this happen?

I use `Android 5.0 API 21`

This is my log cat

Date & Time.571: D/AndroidRuntime(399): Shutting down VM
Date & Time.571: W/dalvikvm(399): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abc/com.example.abc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at com.example.abc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
Date & Time.590: E/AndroidRuntime(399):     ... 11 more
Date & Time.690: I/Process(399): Sending signal. PID: 399 SIG: 9

This is the error message that I get on my emulator
Sorry!
The application abc (process com.example.abc) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

I am using the `Nexus S (4.0", 480 x 800:hdpi) Target Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10` as my Android Virutal Device and I was `not able to change the Target to Android 5.0 - API Level 21` as the OK button was disabled and it said **"No CPU/ABI system image selected"**.

```
 package com.example.abc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Window;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.view.Menu;


  public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {


  LinearLayout layout1, buttonLayout;
  EditText number1Text, number2Text;
  Button calcButton, addButton, subButton, divideButton, multiplyButton;
  TextView answerText, bannerText, result;
  //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
  //actionBar.hide();



  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    number1Text = new EditText(this);
    number2Text = new EditText(this);
    addButton = new Button(this);
    multiplyButton = new Button(this);
    divideButton = new Button(this);

    answerText = new TextView(this);

    answerText.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);
    answerText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //buttonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    buttonLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);



    number1Text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    number2Text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);



    answerText.setWidth(150);
    answerText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    answerText.setText("0");
    addButton.setText("+");

    calcButton.setText("Click to Calculate");

    addButton.setOnClickListener(addClicked);

    layout1.addView(bannerText);
    layout1.addView(number1Text);
    layout1.addView(number2Text);
    layout1.addView(calcButton);
    layout1.addView(buttonLayout);
    layout1.addView(answerText);


    setContentView(layout1);

    number1Text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,50));
    number2Text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,50));
    addButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));

    }

    private OnClickListener addClicked = new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String firstString = number1Text.getText().toString();
                String secondString = number2Text.getText().toString();
                double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
                double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(secondString);

                double result = firstNumber + secondNumber;                     

                String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
                answerText.setText(resultString);
        }
    };



}
```

This is my latest log cat

Date & Time.705: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
Date & Time.705: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abc/com.example.abc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at com.example.abc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
Date & Time.725: E/AndroidRuntime(333):     ... 11 more

I appreciate if someone could kindly let me know why they have voted that this answer was not useful. I have rewritten the code and here it is for everyone else.

```
package com.example.calculate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class MainActivity extends Activity
{


 LinearLayout layout1;
 EditText number1Text;
 EditText number2Text;
 Button calcButton;
 TextView answerText;




   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        number1Text = new EditText(this);
        number2Text = new EditText(this);
        calcButton = new Button(this);
        answerText = new TextView(this);

      layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

      answerText.setText("0");
      calcButton.setText("Press to Calculate");

      calcButton.setOnClickListener(addClicked); 

      layout1.addView(number1Text);
      layout1.addView(number2Text);
      layout1.addView(calcButton);
      layout1.addView(answerText);


      setContentView(layout1);
     }

      private OnClickListener addClicked = new OnClickListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String firstString = number1Text.getText().toString();
            String secondString = number2Text.getText().toString();
            double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
            double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(secondString);
            double result = firstNumber + secondNumber;                     
            String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
            answerText.setText(resultString);
            }
        };

   }
```

Thank you

Comment: Show your MainActivity. Error on line # 57

Comment: I am working on the formatting of the post currently will soon post the MainActivity.

Comment: As checked on the code in notepad++ the line #57 had the code mentioned below which has been commented now but I am still getting the same error. Commented code: //buttonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to setting a text on a null ButtonView i.e.

```
calcButton.setText("Click to Calculate");
```

So firstly create the object of that button and then set the text on that.

Comment: I added an object as mentioned in MainActivity before this "addButton = new Button(this);" and it still did not resolve the problem. calcButton = new Button(this);

Comment: Request yout to help on this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `buttonLayout` is never initialized. this is the reason you are getting null pointer exception

at

```
buttonLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```